# Continuity Help

Tags: continuity, definition

If $\lim_{h \to 0}[f(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)] = 0$ for every $x \in \Bbb R$, does it follow that $f$ is continuous?

I start by rearranging it to be $\lim_{h \to 0}f(x+h)+f(x-h)=\lim_{h \to 0}2f(x)$ and I feel as though I need to rearrange the LHS, but am unsure as to how to proceed.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Counterexample:**
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & x < 0\\
1 & x = 0\\
2 & x > 0
\end{cases}
$$